# Getting the correct event.target for parent elements in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

First off I am using vanilla javascript (no frameworks). 
I am trying to get a click event listener on an element that doesn't exist yet so I am doing this (where `parentElement` exists already):

```
parentElement.addEventListener( "click", function(e){
    console.log(e.target)
} )
```

The thing I am clicking looks like this:

```
<a href="#" class="modal-close">
    <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
</a>
```

I am trying to get the `e.target` to match the `a` tag but it obviously matches the `i` tag since that is what is being clicked. Therefore if I try and match the `A` tag it won't match.

```
console.log(e.target.tagName == "A") //false
```

How can I match that `A` tag instead of it's child (the `i` tag).

I know that if I used jQuery I could just do:

```
$("parentElementThatExists").on("click","a.modal-close",function(e){...
```

That would work just fine. But I am not using jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me

```js
window.onload=function(){
  var x = document.getElementById("x");
  x.addEventListener( "click", function(e){
    console.log(e.target.tagName,e.target.parentNode.tagName)
  })
  x.innerHTML='<a href="#" class="modal-close"><i class="fa fa-times">Click</i></a>'
}
```

```html
<div id="x"></div>
```

Comment: I agree with your solution however in my situation the elements are a little more dynamic so I can't just say "get the parent"

Comment: You can loop up through the Dom until A found

Answer (score 1):

You could just use the `e.currrentTarget` property if you don't mind. Valid for >= IE9.

http://jsfiddle.net/dpatz/6optLe9r/

Comment: if `target` = element that triggered event and `currentTarget` = element that listens to event. What is `currentTarget` in this situation?

Comment: Not the A and it has some compatibility issues: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget

Comment: @mplungjan so as long as you are >=IE9?